# The response from the backend takes too long

Tags: action, callback

After performing the `$A.enqueueAction(anAction);` the response provided with `anAction.setCallback(this, aCallback);` takes too long to execute (I should wait for something like 1-5 minutes after `$A.enqueueAction(anAction);` before the `aCallback` is executed). I checked that there are no errors and the response actually comming every time with a `"SUCCESS"` state.

I happens with every queued action. Are there any ways to make the backend send the response faster? Maybe there is some kind of a prioritization is present?

Comment: We would need some code to know for sure, but it sounds like you're trying to call $A.enqueueAction outside of the component life cycle. Make sure you're following the rules in the [Modifying Components Outside the Framework Lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm) documentation. It should never take more than a second for the server to start processing the action if you're doing so within the component life cycle.

Comment: @sfdcfox, could you please post it as an answer. It helped me out. Or should I delete the question? And where did you happen to read about that thing? I mean there are a lot of gaps I have and I would like systematically fill them.

Comment: Sure, I can add an answer for you. It's all in the documentation, you just need to take the time to read/research it. I can't really explain it to you how **I** do it, because I'm not really sure how I do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that any actions you're calling are called within the framework lifecycle. This typically means that you need to use $A.getCallback in situations where you're not responding to a Lightning Event or a Lightning Callback in order to let the framework know that you're modifying the component or trying to invoke an action. You can read more in the [Modifying Components Outside the Framework Lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm) documentation.